# Isolated singular point- complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that if a function $f$ fails to be analytic at $z_0$ but is analytic at some point in every neighborhood of $z_0$, then $z_0$ is a singular point.

But what is an *isolated* singular point?

Here is the definition from my book: A singular point $z_0$ is said to be *isolated* if, in addition [to being singular], there is a deleted neighborhood $0<|z-z_0|<\epsilon$ of $z_0$ throughout which $f$ is analytic.

I don't fully understand what a deleted neighborhood means. 
Any clarification is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsolatedSingularity.html

Comment: http://www.mathwords.com/d/deleted_nbhd.htm

Comment: please see second link,there is given  definition of  deleted neighorhood

Comment: @dato Oh okay, so it's basically a neighborhood of $z_0$ without $z_0$, right?

Comment: right  ,because    it omits itself

Comment: so i am happy @Alti  if i helped you.good lucks.you are welcome to this great  mathematical website

Comment: @dato Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted Neighborhood

The proper name for a set such as ${x: 0 < |x – a| < δ}$. Deleted neighborhoods are encountered in the study of limits. It is the set of all numbers less than δ units away from a, omitting the number a itself.

Using interval notation the set ${x: 0 < |x – a| < δ} $ would be $(a – δ, a) ∪ (a, a + δ).$ In general, a deleted neighborhood of $a$ is any set $(c, a) ∪ (a, d)$ where $c < a < d.$

For example, one deleted neighborhood of $2$ is the set ${x: 0 < |x – 2| < 0.1}$, which is the same as $(1.9, 2) ∪ (2, 2.1).$